# Multiple threads in spring controller

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I' writing some websockets apllication on spring boot. From front-end there are send request to my controller, and there message is send message to another user, below I show controllers method:

```
private MessagingService messagingService;
private DaoMessageService daoMessageService;

public MessageController(MessagingService messagingService, DaoMessageService daoMessageService){
    this.messagingService = messagingService;
    this.daoMessageService = daoMessageService;
}

@MessageMapping("/hello")
public void sendMessage(MessageDto messageDto, Principal principal) throws InterruptedException {
    String recipient = messageDto.getRecipient();
    String user = principal.getName();

    Message message = new Message(messageDto.getContent());
    message.setSenderName(user);
    message.setRecipient(recipient);

    daoMessageService.saveMessageForUser(user, message);

    messagingService.convertAndSendToUser(recipient, message);
}
```

My question is : If many users will be write messages, there will create some like queue for these message wait for handle by this controller ? Or maybe there are create one controller for request or session scope ? if not, how I can use it asynchronously ? I can't read it anywhere.

Comment: For me the controller is fine. I expect no queue. The same method is entered twice by different threads and each one calls the logic properly. Why queue?

Comment: I think about situation when multi users send messages at the same time, there alwys be one contoller instance so, what happen then ? They could handle all messages at the same time, ye ?

Comment: You should probably check DefferedResult, Callable and @Async.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/07/understanding-callable-and-spring-deferredresult.html

Comment: Thank you :) I will check :)

Comment: Now I now !!! Every request is handle in new thread: "clientInboundChannel-4
clientInboundChannel-6
"